# How to run client side javascript from a get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, http, client-server

I am running a node.js server, and I have an index.html file. The html file has a form with some data, and a script
`<script>document.getElementById("form").submit();</script>`

When I visit the page in a browser, the form submits automatically, sending a post request to the action.

However, if I run a get request in postman or axios to the index.html file, the script does not run, it just returns the text of the index.html file.

I presume this is because the browser runs the script, but how can I simulate this behaviour in node.js?

Comment: I have no idea what your actual question is. Are you running server-side (node) code or not? What request do you want to run, when do you want to run it, and what to you want to do with the result? Re-reading this for the 5th time it sounds like you want to request an HTML document with node, then run the <script> inside? Sounds like a massive [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/) tbh.

Comment: I changed my question @ChrisG

Comment: Instead of loading an HTML document with data in it, why not send the actual request from node directly? Also, when you open the browser and load your index.html, the browser will navigate to the result (i.e. display some page). How do you want this to work with node? console or file output instead? Or do you want node to open a browser and showing the result there? If so, why use node at all? Again, sounds like an xy problem. Please try to describe what your actual goal is. What data is in the form? A login? Search parameters?

Comment: The post request doesn't work in axios, only from an html document. I'm not sure about that 2nd question. I just want to run client side scripts in node.

Comment: That is not how it works though. `I just want to run client side scripts in node` I get that, but I don't think you realize what the difference between in-browser JS and node is. With node, there is no browser, no document, no form, nothing. JS is "just another programming language". Again, what is the form about? What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Is there not a npm module to simlulate a browser? I am sending a post request to a different server that won't let me send requests that don't come from the browser, but I still want to send them autonomously.

Comment: Yes, you can use [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) for that. That might not be necessary though, depending on *what the form does*. Are you trying to spam some online survey or something? Because you can fool the server into thinking the request is coming from a browser. We need more information though. What form are we talking about?

Comment: Also note that you have to simulate *sending the form* in postman, not opening the index file. Doing this with postman means you need to run a POST request to the form's action (the actual URL), not your own index.html file. postman doesn't simulate a browser, it simulates submitting the form.

Comment: It is a form I have to fill out every single time I join public wifi, I have figured out how to have it do everything automatically, but I haven't been able to get it to think it is coming from a browser. I have checked the request headers and body and stuff in dev tools when it works and copied that to postman and axios, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The header needs `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the body needs `x-www-form-urlencoded` as type and the `name` attributes from the form as keys. Do you have all that?

Comment: I would doubt if the receiving end is checking from what device comes the request. Did you try to send request data url encoded rather than in a body?

Comment: Yeah and Origin, Accept, Accept-Language, Host, User-Agent, Referer, Accept-Encoding, Connection, with the params and the body

Comment: I have not tried that @arturasmckwcz, but when I use devtools the form data is part of the request body

Comment: @Zac so you've copy-pasted the body and all headers and still doesn't go through does it?

Comment: @arturasmckwcz it just returns the form html as if I did a get request to the browser. On a success, it returns a checkmark, but I have not gotten that in postman.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ChrisG I used puppeteer and it worked, but it opened up a browser every time. Would it still work if it was dockerized and put on a server?

Comment: Maybe, but you cannot access the server without logging in first I guess?